# Observer design pattern: value observer and variable observer implementation

Tags: javascript

Observer implementation that leverages both behaviours observing a variable and observing for a value. Supports subscribing and withdrawing observers.

```
var Diffuser = (function() {
    return { supply: function() {
        return (function() {
            var diffusees = [];
            var oneTimeDiffusees = [];
            
            var withdraw = function (value) {

                var once = function(values) {
                    var index = values.indexOf(value);
                    if ( index > -1 ) {
                        values.splice(index, 1);

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                };
                var remover = once;

                return { from: function(values) {
                                   return remover(values);
                         }
                       , entierly: function() {

                                       remover = function(values) {
                                                     var index = values.indexOf(value);
                                                     if ( index == -1 ) { return false; }
                                                     for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
                                                         if ( values[i] === value ) {
                                                             values.splice(i, 1);
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                     return true;
                                                 };

                                       return this;
                       }
                     , once: function() {

                                 remover = once;

                                 return this;
                     }};
            };
            
            return {
                diffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    diffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , oneTimeDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , withdraw: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(diffusees);
                }
                , withdrawOneTimeDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(oneTimeDiffusees);
                }
                , diffuse: function(diffused) {
                    var diffuseFunction = function() {
                        diffusees.forEach( (diffusee) => { (function() { diffusee(diffused); })(); });
                    };
                    var oneTimeDiffuseFunction = function() {
                        for ( var i = 0; i < oneTimeDiffusees.length; i++ ) {
                            var diffusee = oneTimeDiffusees.pop();
                            if ( !(function() { return diffusee(diffused); })() ) {
                                oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout( function() { 
                        
                        diffuseFunction();
                        oneTimeDiffuseFunction();
                        
                    }, 0);
                }
            };
        })();
    } };
})();
```

Usage example:

```
var crunch = (function() {

    var oneTimeListener = (function() {
        var aLetter = “a”;
        var theCodeToRunForALetter = () => {};
        return (listenedValue) => { 
            if ( listenedValue != aLetter ) { return false; }

            theCodeToRunForALetter();

            return true;
        };
    } )();

    var listener = (value) => {};

    var observed = Diffuser.supply();
    observed.diffuseTo(listener);
    observed.diffuseTo(oneTimeListener);

    return (toCrunch) => {
        Array.from(toCrunch).forEach( (letter) => { observed.diffuse(letter); } );
    };
})();

crunch("some text to crunch");
```

Answer (score 1):

## be generic

```
        var aLetter = “a”;
        var theCodeToRunForALetter = () => {};
```

The library generically implements Observer pattern over the elements of an array.
Consider presenting this function in a more generic way
by renaming "letter" to "element".

Alternatively, consider offering a bit of scaffolding "in between",
so the example may easily consume an "element" abstraction
that immediately grounds out to a character or "letter".

You could offer a more instructive function than the
rather hypothetical `theCodeToRunForALetter()`,
perhaps something that counts vowels.
OIC, that use case would require a more flexible predicate.
Maybe something that counts occurences of `"a"`.

---

## quadratic complexity

My reading of the
[spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.splice)
is that `.splice()` is required to take O(n) linear time.

```
                    var index = values.indexOf(value);
                        ...
                        values.splice(index, 1);
```

I *think* you're computing `once` one time for each element of `values`?
In which case we're O(n^2) quadratic in number of values.
Consider overwriting with a
[tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming))
sentinel instead.

Potentially quadratic, depending on whether we have lots of repeated values,
such as boolean values:

```
                                             for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
                                                     ...
                                                     values.splice(i, 1);
```

If the caller can expect O(n) linear behavior for typical inputs,
spell out in the documentation what those inputs would look like.

---

## one time

```
            var oneTimeDiffusees = [];
```

Sorry, I didn't get that concept.
Citing an URL would go a long way toward explaining its motivation.

There seems to be some review context missing,
at least for the example call, but hey,
we'll take what we can get and run with it.
Certainly the crunch() example has pedagogic value
that helps motivate the library -- thank you for that.

As an app developer calling into this library,
I could use some more clarity on what I'm responsible for passing in
and what I can expect of the library's behavior.
Partly this is due to the "hello world" example
needing more lines of code than I would anticipate.

```
                       , entierly: function() {
```

nit, typo: Please use standard spelling of `entirely`.

---

## conventional terminology

The verb "diffuse" is fine, you can certainly leave it as-is.

But consider renaming to "subscribe", more in line with the literature.
One encounters "subscriber" far more often than "diffusee".
The similarity between "diffuser" and "diffusee" seems unhelpfully distracting.

---

## documentation

The explanatory prose accompanying this submission is very nice.
It does not appear in the source code, and it absolutely should.

Several of the interior functions need comments, including returned functions.

Comment: `diffuse` - and its conjugations - is far from fine. It actively thwarts comprehension.  Where is the "observer/subscriber?"  Where is a/the/any pattern? `diffuseness` is a noun but how we get from "to pour out and cause to spread, as a fluid" to a subscriber or observable is baffling. I should stop and re-read but I'm still on the first line.  The `Usage Example` looks like missing implementation not a use case.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was trying too hard to be kind, to not assign action items prior to merge-to-main. I agree that it thwarts comprehension.